# Avoiding awkwardness in the team/workplace when looking for a new job

Tags: job-search

I'm currently 2 years into my first job as a software developer.

Ours is a small city, and has limited growth potential, so now I want to move to another job in a larger city. For this I have uploaded my résumé to some job websites, and I get calls from recruiters about new openings.

Now, this would otherwise be perfectly okay: people work for a while here, gain experience and then leave to pursue larger opportunities all the time. But in my case, I was promoted to tech lead in February, and it feels awkward to be pursuing other job opportunities when you've got people reporting to you. Plus, I have other responsibilities too; like conducting interviews and managing the code for the main projects we work on.

About my boss and other senior people in the company: they've been very good to me these two years. I originally came here from an internal informal reference, and I also did well, and was respected by them for that. Letting them down is another thing I'm afraid of.

As is evident above, I'm stuck in a dilemma. I know I will have to leave to go elsewhere one day, but answering calls from recruiters in the midst of my juniors and people who report to me feels awkward.

Edit: I have a physical disability, so unlike others, I cannot go outside to receive calls. Phone calls aren't usually allowed in the office, but I receive calls on my desk, and everyone has adjusted to that.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of advice you're looking for here. How awkward it feels mostly comes down to your own mindset and there isn't much we can help with there. You already "know I will have to leave to go elsewhere one day". Of course talking to recruiters while next to coworkers is not a good idea.

Comment: Write on the job websites that you can be contacted by email and are available for phone calls after 8 pm. You shouldn't do your job search during working hours.

Comment: It's generally not unreasonable to ask to be called during a certain time interval or to step outside to take a call.

Comment: "How do I prevent my coworkers overhearing me talking to recruiters" might be a better way to phrase this question, if that's what you want to know.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: Your edit answers the clarification I asked for, so I have deleted my obsolete comment. Nonetheless, I have to ask how do you normally deal with *other* personal calls? Do you take them from the desk as well? I wouldn't ask about the details of your disability, but just wondering how difficult is it for you to leave the office and come back to your desk? The answer should ideally take that into account.

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 I have difficulty standing for long periods of time, so I can't take calls outside where I have to take the call standing up. That's why I take personal calls at my desk.

Answer (score 14):

> but answering calls from recruiters in the midst of my juniors and
>   people who report to me feels awkward.

There's no real dilemma here.

You shouldn't be answering calls from recruiters in the middle of your workplace.

If you don't have a private location, specify that recruiters call you after hours, or get a callback number and call them from a quiet location where your conversation can't be overheard or later once you get home.

Comment: At present, I just tell them that I'll call back when I'm able to.

Answer (score 3):

The practicality of the situation is that HR/recruiters are doing their job during the exact same work hours as the rest of us. And if your current job isn't where you see your future, you're going to be looking for another one. It sounds like you're conscientious about still doing your job while you're starting too look, so don't let guilt trap you. It sounds like people moving on is a regular thing, and when you do go, if you've done good work and you're moving to something that is better for you, there should be no hard feelings.

As where/when/how to have those calls, I'm inferring that your office doesn't have any kind of occasional tele-commuting policy that would make that easier. You can try specifying that you'd prefer to be contacted by email, or at certain times. I have some friends that actually use such tactics to screen recruiters that actually read their resume from those that just do keyword searches and try to grab anyone that comes up.  In any case they should be very open to you telling them "Thanks, but I'm right in the middle of something. Can I call you back/send you an email?" And set a better time to talk to them when you can get away for a while. Or even ask them to send you an email you can respond to if taking a note of their contact info is problematic. And assuming they're not calling your work phone (that could be problematic) just let them roll to voice mail and check messages at a better time. They know you're at work and it may not be possible to have any kind of protracted conversation.

You have a job right now, and it may not be where you want to stay for the next several years, but you also don't have to find a new one immediately. Under those circumstances any recruiter/potential employer that doesn't understand that your current job has to take priority isn't representing a place you'd probably want to work anyway.

Comment: Setting specific hours/communicating through email is the course that I think I'm going to take.

Answer (score -2):

You are afraid of letting down your supervisors:
It appears you have mutual trust between your superiors and yourself. It also looks like you are good at what you do. So you are likely to land the new job you seek.

I'd seriously consider the effect of dropping the fact that you are moving on as a surprise move to your supervisors. If they have to fill your position suddenly, with little time for handover, you will badly affect your relationship with them. It is a small world, whether you work there again or not, the way you part ways will affect your future career.

Consider telling everyone upfront that you are looking for a new job. Make sure your performance at the current job is not affected by your plans to move and this is very visible to everyone. This will give your company to arrange the necessary handovers, your peers will respect your honesty and your work ethic.

That said, the other answers here very well cover how to minimize being on the phone with recruiters.

Comment: It is perhaps kindhearted to give advance notice, but can work against you -- I know someone who gave 6 months notice, attempting to be nice, and was immediately fired. People change jobs all the time, and there's a reason (in the US anyway) two weeks is standard notice.

Comment: It looks like cst1992 has already answered calls. Letting the boss know will likely reduce the odds of the boss finding out and firing them.

Comment: Thanks for the viewpoint, but that is not an issue. The bosses have let me know that I'm free to leave whenever I want(in the good sense) -- they'll not stop me. And there is enough notice period in the signing clause for someone to be hired to fill my position.